# How Can I Draw Objects in Kivy Without Using the kv Language?

Tags: python, draw, kivy

I've been following in this [tutorial](http://kivy.org/docs/tutorials/pong.html), the section "Add Simple Graphics". But I'm having trouble getting the program to draw the images. Kivy isn't detecting the *pong.kv* file, and I've tried everything I can think of. Does anyone know of a way to draw objects in kivy without using the kv language?

EDIT: Sorry for not saying this before. I'd rather lose the kv file.

Comment: It's actually quite easy, but you have to be more specific. And do you really want to ditch the .kv file, or would it be better to get it working?

Answer (score 1):

As Mark suggested, it would be best to get the .kv file working. You should tell us what you've tried and we can try to spot the problem. However, it is possible to draw the graphics without:

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(PongBall, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    with self.canvas:
        Color(1,1,1,1)
        self.ball = Ellipse(size=[50,50],pos=[150,150])
```

Here I've just created a white ball of a given size at a given position. You can also add other properties or other graphical objects here.

(I haven't tested the above so apologies if it contains errors).

Hope that helps a bit.